# shell_exec | allow specific program to run under apache user

Tags: php, linux, centos, shell-exec

can i run specific command/program like x server that need root privileges using shell_exec from php. i just want to run x server program from php shell_exec(). 
note: php is running under suphp, OS is centos.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look for SUID und SGID on Unix Files

[SUID stands for Set User ID. This means that if the SUID bit is set for any application then your user ID would be set as that of the owner of application/file rather than the current user, while running that application. That means in case I have an application whose owner is ' root ' and it has its SUID bit set, then when I run this application as a normal user, that application would still run as root. Since the SUID bit tells Linux that the the User ID root is set for this application and whenever this application executes it must execute as if root was executing it (since root owns this file).](http://www.codecoffee.com/tipsforlinux/articles/028.html)